# Will this JavaScript code garbage-collect the way I expect?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, xmlhttprequest

```
function fetchXmlDoc(uri) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var async = false;
    xhr.open("GET", uri, async);
    xhr.send();

    return xhr.responseXML;
}
```

Basically, when I call this function, will the `xhr` object get garbage-collected, or will it stick around forever because the caller is holding on to `xhr.responseXML`? If it's the latter, would this solve it?

```
function fetchXmlDoc2(uri) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var async = false;
    xhr.open("GET", uri, async);
    xhr.send();

    var xml = xhr.responseXML;
    return xml;
}
```

Despite all my years of JS, the whole memory-management thing still manages to confuse me...

Comment: PS I know Jax (i.e. Ajax without the A) is usually bad, but in this case it's working with the local filesystem, so it's not so bad.

Comment: That depends on e.g. whether `xhr.responseXML` holds a reference to `xhr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The responseXML property of the xhr object is a reference to the actual data object (just as you've implicitly assumed in the second piece of code: you're not copying the data, you're copying the reference).

So the `xhr` object will eventually get garbage collected. There is only one reference to it: right here in this function where it's created.

Comment: Right, OK, so I should picture some "box" in memory containing a `Document` object, which `xhr.responseXML` is a reference to. But by returning `xhr.responseXML`, I am creating a new reference to that "box", unrelated to the one that's associated to `xhr`. Makes sense now that I think about it... thanks!!